# Continuity of greatest integer function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define 
$$
f(x):x \rightarrow[[x]].
$$
Prove that $f$ is continuous if $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Please use the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of a limit.

Note: I understand why does it happens.Need to write systematically with proper statements, essentially required for college exams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $x_0$ is not an integer; then $n<x_0<n+1$, for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then there is an $\delta>0$ such that $x_0-\delta>n$ and $x_0+\delta<n+1$. What can you say about the function $f(x)$ for $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$? On this neighborhood, the function simplifies greatly; you should be able to prove continuity at $x_0$ directly from this.

As for showing that $f$ is not continuous at $x\in\mathbb{Z}$: think about left vs right limits.

Comment: for showing a function to be continuous we start with an arbitary epsilon what about that?

Comment: Right.  So you're given $\epsilon>0$, and you want to find some $\delta>0$ so that $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta$ implies $\lvert f(x_0)-f(x)\rvert<\epsilon$. All that I'm saying - and the entire key to solving the problem - is that you can choose $\delta$ smaller than the $\delta$ I gave you... and in so doing, you're dealing with a (locally) linear function!

Comment: In particular, what happens if you consider $\delta_0$ such that $\delta_0<\delta$ (the $\delta$ I gave above) AND $\delta_0<\epsilon$?

Comment: take minimum of them!